# Netflix Arcaius serving as config service for multiple Spring Boot micro-services

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-archaius, configserver

I'm having a problem with how to use just Netflix Archaius to work as a config server for multiple Spring Boot microservices. Previously when I applied Eureka and Spring Cloud Config Server in my multiple-services project built with Spring Boot, each microservie would get its own .properties file from the Spring Cloud Config server through the discovery function of the Eureka service. But now I need to change the Spring Cloud Config Server into a Netflix Archaius service, from which the Spring Boot microservices will get .properties file, i have no idea about how to achieve it. Is there any good idea for my reference? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I gave up using Netflix Archaius to pull properties file for microservices. Instead, I wrote down required key-value-pair properties into the application.properties of each springboot microservice. Since all the springboot microservices will be deployed in the DCOS platform in the form of docker containers, some inconstant properties were configured into the marathon deployment scripts, which could be populated into the springboot applet. In this way I managed to configure the key-value-pair properties from the outside instead of being hardcoded in the program codes.

Comment: Why not use Microservices specific key value pairs in the datastore and use Archaius to load then from the datastore using a JDBC based poller?